# Angular 2: how to change @Input property value during ngOnInit/ngOnChanges

Tags: angular, typescript

### Problem

I am creating a component with 2 `@Input()` properties, and they happen to depend on one another. Here's an example (also you can see [this plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/EItx5AQxKKKrWPhzbijq?p=preview)):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-select',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of items">
        {{ item }}
        <span *ngIf="item === default">(default)</span>
        <button *ngIf="item !== default" (click)="makeDefault(item)">Make default</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
}) export class MyInput implements OnInit {
  @Input() public items: string[] = [];

  @Input() public defaultValue: string;
  @Output() public defaultValueChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

  public makeDefault(item: string): void {
    this.defaultValue = item;
    this.defaultValueChange.emit(this.defaultValue);
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    if (!this.defaultValue) {
      // choose the first item, since there always must be a default
      this.makeDefault(this.items[0]);
    }
  }
}
```

The actual problem is that I'm changing an `@Input()` property value during an ongoing change-detection cycle, which is not very awesome (and result in an error thrown by Angular). This is happening assuming that

```
<my-select [(default)]="defaultItem" ...></my-select>
```

syntax is used, which is exactly the expected usage pattern.

I can fix this by surrounding `makeDefault` call with `setTimeout`, like this:

```
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    if (!this.defaultValue) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.makeDefault(this.items[0]);
      }, 0);
    }
  }
```

but this is pretty ugly, IMHO.

What is the proper way to handle such interaction patterns?

Answer (score 0):

To set the default value, you must use:

```
[defaultValue]="default"
```

Not:

```
[(defaultValue)]="default"
```

Check out the updated [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/oEHemlzBQwZKz2JRxBxf?p=preview). I wired up the defaultValueChange event too.

**Update from comment:**

Also, instead of initializing 'default' in the my-app template, using a default value declared in the App class overcomes this issue too:

```
<my-select [(default)]="defaultItem" ...></my-select>

export class App {
  defaultItem = 'default';
  items = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'];
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}
```

Comment: The "banana-in-a-box" is expected usage here. I want to listen to property change from the outside. And yes, it's a part of the problem, but this is something that I cannot change. I'll update my question with this remark

Comment: Is there a reason you need to initialize 'default' in the my-app template? Using a default value declared in the App class instead will also overcome this issue. Updated the answer above.

Comment: yes, it definitely overcomes the issue. I'm trying to make the control resistant to user errors. And the user might forget to assign a `default` value or assign it to something invalid. Thus, I'm setting the `default` myself in such cases

Comment: Yes, I can understand that. But two-way data binding to a value declared in a template is what's upsetting Angular.

Comment: Yup :) But frankly I  don't think that such a use-case is unique, so I want to get this sorted out